# Nullspace of $Ax=b$ Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

I know how to find the nullspace of matrix in the form $Ax=0$. But how can I get the nullspace for an $Ax=b$ style matrix? I leave an example question:

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&3&1\\2&2&5&1\\1&2&1&1\end{bmatrix},$$
$$
x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\end{bmatrix},$$
$$
b=\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\0\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Question: Write down a basis for $N(A)$, the nullspace of $A$.

Comment: Please show some effort. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: This site is not a "do my work for me service", wndpzr.

Comment: As noted that the nullspace is of a matrix, but if you are looking for the solutions of the matrix equation $Ax=b$, then it is the translation of the nullspace of $A$ by a particular solution. Note it could also be the case that no solutions exist.

Comment: The problem you quoted asks about the nullspace of $A$.  That can be answered regardless of whether $A$ is being used elsewhere to pose an equation $Ax = b$.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The nullspace of A is defined as the set of vectors x which will be mapped to the zero vector if multiplied by A i.e.
$$N(A) = \{x: Ax = 0\}$$
Therefore, I don't think this question is valid, since Ax = b is not a matrix.

If you are searching for the nullspace of A, you need to solve the equation $$Ax = 0$$